# What is the temp location/path for Adobe CC 2014 setup file?

Tags: windows, path, installation, exe

I installed Adobe CC 2014 and would like to save the setup file. I reinstall my computer quite offen therefore backup the setup file could save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's creating temporary folders for every application download in \Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\

To find out exactly when, open resmon (run->resmon) go to disk and click on disk activity.

This way you'll see where it's some massive data write... and that should be the place, if you don't have any other heavy writing process.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily finally solved the problem.

You need 2 steps to obtain the path.

And you have to do this quickly while Adobe installer is installing your file. Once the installation is done, it seems to clean out the setup file.

Step 1: check out C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Installers. Say if you're installing Dreamweaver, then you can see a file called "Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2014 14.0.0 08-31-2014.log"

Step 2: Open it with txt editor, search for the term "deploymentFile". The path next to it is exact where the setup file is located.